# using server variables in a href <%= xx %> with runat=server

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use an anchor tag on an aspx page as below,

```
<a href="~/pages/page.aspx?id=<%= ServervariableName %>"> test </a>
```

it will get the variable value correctly assigned to id but it won't route the page correctly as the ~ will not be evaluated without the runat="server" attribute on the 'a' tag. But once I add the runat server attribute, it does not evaluate the servervariable name anymore.. Does anyone know how this works or what I should do to take care of both?

Comment: ok, it took out my <a> tag section... let me add it again.. [  a href "~/pages/page.aspx?id=<% servervariablename %>"] test [/a].. just replaced some of < with [

Comment: You should format your code by indenting it with four spaces.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following:

```
href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/pages/page.aspx") + "?id=" + ServervariableName %>"
```

This will only work if you do not add `runat="server"`.

Comment: @Letseatlunch - Thank you. Updated the answer. To be honest: it's been years since I've developed asp.net. Thought I'd try an answer. I'll just stay out of the `asp.net` tag I think :D.

Comment: Yes, forgot about the resolveurl function. Thank you very much, it worked and is exactly what i was looking for. Its a menu item that needs to pass in a value dynamically.. so..!

Comment: Heres a create work around if you ever need to use resolveUrl in a non "Page/Control" context: www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/resolveurl.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use this syntax to set properties of server-side controls.

Instead, you can set the property in the code-behind, or use data-binding syntax (`<%# expression %>`) and call `DataBind()` in the code-behind.

Answer (score 2):

If you want both runat=server and a virtual path you either of:

1. Set the href in your code behind. Afaik MapPath doesn't remove query strings.
2. If you don't want to use MapPath, you can use [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.toabsolute.aspx) which MapPath uses internally most likely.
3. If you want to bind the variable in your .aspx-file and still want runat="server", then you have to use [an expression builder](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Expression-Builder.aspx). You syntax then becomes

   <a href="~/folder/page.aspx?id=<%$ MyVars:ServerVariableName %>" runat="server">The link</a>

PM me if you need help with it. It's quite useful for customizing localization and for interfacing the ASP.Net compiler (i.e. not the C#/VB one, but the one that can compile ASPX-pages)

Comment: The expression builders is a really cool which I didn't know about. Thanks for letting me know. Is there an easy way to declare a page variable and convert that to an expression?

Comment: By a "page variable", what do you mean? A protected field of the class that the page compiles to? In fact, what the expression builder does is invoked by the CodeDom at ASP.Net's compile time and the implementation lets you emit any code you want. I'm pretty you could make the MyVars-expression builder emit the code to access a field, although I haven't done it.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not exactly sure why `runat="server"` prevents the evaluation of `<%= Property =>`, but you need `runat="server`" to evaluate the ~ root.  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx),

> You can use the ~ operator in any
>   path-related property in server
>   controls. The ~ operator is recognized
>   only for server controls and in server
>   code. You cannot use the ~ operator
>   for client elements.

Anyways, this might get you going.

ASPX

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="myHyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/MyPage.aspx?id=<%=MyProperty %>" Text="Click Me" />
```

CS

```
myHyperLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/MyPage.aspx?id={0}", MyProperty);
```

Comment: yes, but i did not want to use a hyperlink. The "resolveurl" function did the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that right after I posted =) Glad you got it working!

Comment: This solution does not work : the server tags are not interpreted.