# using <%= %> or <%# %> with runat=server in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webcontrol

I have a web control that looks like this

```
public class Foo : WebControl
{
  [Bindable(true)]
  [Category("Default")]
  [DefaultValue("")]
  [Localizable(true)]
  public string Bar { get; set; }

  protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
  {
    output.WriteLine(Bar);
  }
}
```

I want to put this webcontrol in my aspx page like so:

```
<cc1:Foo Bar="<%= Fa.La.La %>/otherstuff" runat="server" />
```

(obviously this code is simplified to show the problem)

In my Render method the variable Fa.La.La is not evaluated.  It's coming in as the raw text "<%= Fa.La.La %>" How do I evaluate it?

I'm not particular how the variables are passed in. If the variables can be evaluated if they are passed in as <%# ... %>, that works fine.  The point is I have some server-side variables I want evaluated before/while my Render() method is called.

The only thing I can think of is to use a regex to grab the contents of <%= ... %> and use reflection or something, but there has to be a more elegant way to do this.

This question is pretty similar to [using server variables in a href <%= xx %> with runat=server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4306850/24267), but it's not exactly the same since none of the answers there were useful.

Comment: Try using this <cc1:Foo Bar='<%= Fa.La.La %>/otherstuff' runat="server" /> NOTE single quote and double quote difference. I hope it may solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have to use  binding expression `<%# expr %>`.

```
<cc1:Foo Bar='<%# String.Concat(Fa.La.La,"/otherstuff")%>' runat="server" />
```

and call `DataBind()` method in code-behind.

```
public void page_load()
{
  DataBind();
}
```

Comment: To expand on this answer, you can't do something like:
Bar="<%# Fa.La.La %>/otherstuff"
It just gets rendered literally.
The databinding expression has to be the only thing in the attribute, e.g., 
Bar='<%# String.Concat(Fa.La.La, "/otherstuff") %>'
Furthermore, the outside quotes should be single-quotes and the inside quotes should be double-quotes (assuming C#, anyway).

Answer (score 6):

Well, first you should be clear to diff between both tags.
here are some points i have read and used practically..

- The `<%=` expressions are evaluated at render time
- The `<%#` expressions are evaluated at `DataBind()` time and are not evaluated at all if
  DataBind() is not called.
- `<%#` expressions can be used as properties
  in server-side controls.`<%=` expressions cannot.

read more it on [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx)