# Why Semicolon (;) Expected error occurs

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, hyperlink, query-string

I have passed `QueryString` in `hyperlink` like below.

```
<a href="Property_Detail_Search.aspx?P_ID="+<%Request.QueryString["Property_Id"]%>
       itemprop="url"><span itemprop="streetAddress">

   <asp:Label ID="lblPNo" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
</a>
```

Comment: You probably meant `<%=` instead of plain `<%`.

Comment: The error occurs because the complier is looking for a semicolon (;) and you have not provided one. If you use the method noted by @FrédéricHamidi you will not need a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `<% %>` in properties of Server side controls.

It should be as

```
<a href="Property_Detail_Search.aspx?P_ID="+<%# Request.QueryString["Property_Id"] #%
       itemprop="url"><span itemprop="streetAddress">
```

`<%#` expressions can be used as properties in server-side controls.`<%= expressions` cannot be used in ServerSide control's properties.

Read more it on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx). Also you could read another answer i had given on this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11928418/1490287)

Answer (score 0):

You try to add `property_Id` value which comes from addressbar.  write `=` character before `Request.QueryString["Property_Id"]`

```
<a href="Property_Detail_Search.aspx?P_ID="+<%=Request.QueryString["Property_Id"]%>
   itemprop="url"><span itemprop="streetAddress">
```