# How to pick up AppSettings from Web.Config into NavigateURL property on ASPX menu control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Need to  pick up AppSettings key from Web.Config into NavigateURL property on ASPX menu control:
Applied as follows :

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://<%$AppSettings:urlkey%>/index1.aspx"
                                    Text="index page" Value="index page"></asp:MenuItem>
```

where

The above code not working! plz help

Comment: When posting a question, please try to explain _what_ isn't working - eg what you expected to happen and what actually happened. In this case, did you get any errors? Did it fail silently? Did you get an unexpected Url? Incidentally, did you mean to do `<%=` instead of `<%`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the server tags `<%= ... %>` syntax within an ASP.NET server control element declaration. You should set this in the codebehind instead.

Also where is your `runat="server"` ?

Finally check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306975/61697) as it might help you some more.